# Multiple conditions and outcomes in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone correct this? See where I'm going wrong?

```
row_length = 4
ic = 1
pc = 2

newlist = [('') if not x == ic and not x == pc else ('RESERVED ID')
if x == ic ('RESERVED PARENT') if x == pc for x in range(row_length)]
```

Should end up with:

```
newlist = ['RESERVED ID', 'RESERVED PARENT', '', '']
```

Comment: sorry, edited to adjust integer values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
newlist = [''] * row_length
newlist[ic-1] = 'RESERVED ID'
newlist[pc-1] = 'RESERVED PARENT'
```

Not everything has to be done in a list comprehension. My code is not only more efficient but what is more important is easy to read.

---

**EDIT** Here's your one-liner. But please, don't! Be kind to potential people that will read your code some day:

```
newlist = ['RESERVED ID' if idx == ic-1 else 'RESERVED PARENT' if idx == pc-1 else '' for idx in range(row_length)]
```

Comment: Could do it that way in this case but I was curious if I could do it on one line, got a lot of list comprehension coming up due to function binding